# DLLs using different SDKs

Tags: c++, windows, sdk

Are there any potential issues if some dlls use one version of Windows SDK and other libraries use a different version?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: no, must no be any issuers, if no errors in dlls. sdk - this is only general headers files. that describe windows interface.

Comment: Yes you have to be very careful using new / delete (etc) and don't new in one DLL and delete in another.  Also any functions creating / consuming standard library objects (containers) must not cross DLL boundaries (incase allocation/deallocation) happens and ABI differences.  Stick to pure `C` interfaces and manage memory carefully.

Comment: @RichardCritten - are new/delete part of Windows SDK or CRT ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are potential issues. C++ does not have a standardized stable ABI (Application Binary Interface). So, as soon as you move outside of functions with C linkage you are at the mercy of your compiler (and they are *not* known to be binary compatible between versions).
If you stick to C functions, then you can usually expect compatibility.

The best rule of thumb is, though; compile *all* code with *the same* compiler.

Comment: sane <--> same :)  +1 for that :)

Comment: I should have mentioned that the dlls built with a different SDK expose C interface only. The rest of the project is in C++

Comment: windows sdk describe not c/c++ but windows interface. compatible not with sdk at all, but with **windows**. if both dlls compatible with windows (built-in windows binaries) - it compatible between themselves. this not depend from sdk version or compiler